# Rails 4 Comments Div refreshing with other users' comments

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

My goal is that when somebody posts a comment, after 5 seconds, everybody else on the same page will see that comment added without having to refresh the page.

What I have done is setup an interval for every 5 seconds to refresh my div and render @microposts which is equal to current_video.microposts.all

I see on the server log that it is refreshing every 5 seconds, but nothing is changing... it still shows the same microposts, no new ones. My code is below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/static_pages/refresher"
        });
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Home page html

```
<div class="microposts" id="reload">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </div>
```

Refresher.js.erb

```
$("#reload").html('<%= j render @microposts %>');
```

Static Pages Controller

```
def refresher
    @microposts = current_video.microposts.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

Routes

```
get 'static_pages/refresher' => 'static_pages#refresher'
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you open the webinspector, what does it say is actually returned from the request?

Comment: You can use Rails 5 Action cable. For best tutorials follow Go Rails Action Cable

Comment: Looks like it was working after all... it just wasn't scrolling to the bottom so I didn't notice it was there. Having me look at webinspector lead me to figuring that out. Thank you for the tip